# Adding all borders to a selected range, is there a shorter way to write the code?

Tags: excel, vba, border

I am adding all borders to a certain range, In my case (A6:O6),in excel VBA, the below code works but I'd imagine there would have to be a shorter way to write it.  I found a single line of code that puts a border around the whole selection but not around every cell.

```
Range("A6:O6").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
```

Comment: Do you want borders around every cell?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the below statements

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Range("A6:O6")

With myRange.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this. It will add a border around every cell in the range A6:O6.

```
Sub Macro1()
     Dim rng As Range
     ' Define range
     Set rng = Range("A6:O6")

     With rng.Borders
         .LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .Weight = xlThin
         .ColorIndex = 0
         .TintAndShade = 0
     End With
End Sub
```